# Data frame inverse reshaping memory

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So I have two dataframs that I'm using on a GRU model.
 I had to reshape them in order to apply it, but at the end of the code I wanted to plot y_predicted with y_test. It works but what used to be the x-axis is now the y-axis and vice versa. I though that it was because the data was reshaped so I applied `.reshape(1,-1)` but every time I do it I run out of memory (25GB) and I really don't know how to fix this problem

**EDIT:**
So I have dont everything using sample data, and discovered that reshaping y_predict doesn't take memory at all. but this line uses all 25GB of memory for some reason `y_test = y_scale.inverse_transform(y_test)`

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import GRU
from keras.models import Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorboardcolab import tensorboard
# Loading First Dataframe


df = pd.read_csv('IF 10 PERCENT.csv',index_col=None)




df2 = pd.read_csv('2019 10minutes IF 10 PERCENT.csv',index_col=None)


tbc=TensorBoardColab() # Tensorboard




X_train= df[['WindSpeed_mps','AmbTemp_DegC','RotorSpeed_rpm','RotorSpeedAve','NacelleOrientation_Deg','MeasuredYawError','Pitch_Deg','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','GeneratorTemperature_DegC','GearBoxTemperature_DegC']]
X_train=X_train.values

y_train= df['Power_kW']
y_train=y_train.values

X_test= df2[['WindSpeed_mps','AmbTemp_DegC','RotorSpeed_rpm','RotorSpeedAve','NacelleOrientation_Deg','MeasuredYawError','Pitch_Deg','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','GeneratorTemperature_DegC','GearBoxTemperature_DegC']]
X_test=X_test.values

y_test= df2['Power_kW']
y_test=y_test.values

# conversion to numpy array



# scaling values for model


x_scale = MinMaxScaler()
y_scale = MinMaxScaler()

X_train= x_scale.fit_transform(X_train)
y_train= y_scale.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1,1))
X_test=  x_scale.fit_transform(X_test)
y_test=  y_scale.fit_transform(y_test.reshape(-1,1))



X_train = X_train.reshape((-1,1,12)) 
X_test = X_test.reshape((-1,1,12))


# splitting train and test





# creating model using Keras
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(units=512, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1,12)))
model.add(GRU(units=256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(GRU(units=256))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss=['mse'], optimizer='adam',metrics=['mae']) 
model.summary() 


history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=1, validation_data=(X_test,y_test),validation_split=0.1, verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc)])

score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('Score: {}'.format(score))
y_predicted = model.predict(X_test)
y_predicted = y_scale.inverse_transform(y_predicted)
y_test = y_scale.inverse_transform(y_test)
plt.plot( y_predicted, label='Predicted')
plt.plot(  y_test, label='Measurements')
plt.legend()
plt.show()



plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Thank you.

Comment: The problem here is it copies data into memory and in the reshape docs also it is specified that _It is not always possible to change the shape of an array without copying the data_. So probably try it with a section of the input data and check whether you get the same error.

Comment: Like take a sample of the dataframe and test the code on it?

Comment: Yes, a smaller batch size might fit within the memory constraints.

Comment: Yeah I'm doing it now, and whatever I do nothing changes. reshape(-1,1) or reshapre (1,-1)